# RODBC - sqlSave - Append Operation Crashes R

Tags: r, rodbc

I'm trying to save the following dataframe to a SQL Server 2014 table:

```
Observations: 1
Variables: 4
$ ValidationDate <chr> "2016-08-23"
$ DataType       <chr> "Panel"
$ MissingData    <chr> "{\"SubId\":[160823030720,160823030721,160823030722,160823030723,16082303072...
$ Comments       <chr> "Missing in ODS"
```

I'm executing the following R code:

sqlSave(odsHandle, df, tablename = "Utility.DailyDataValidation", append = T)

When this lines executes, there is a pause for perhaps 15 seconds and then R crashes with the following error:

[image]

Comment: `sqlSave` with `append=TRUE` is notoriously finicky.

Comment: @Carl - Yes, so I'm finding out. About 5 minutes ago I read another SO post on this that said it almost never works. I guess I need to find another solution.

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own insert statement and loop through your data. Not ideal, but gets job done

Comment: @Carl - Yup, just converted my sqlSave to sqlQuery using an Insert Into and it works great. If you wanted to create this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlSave` with `append=TRUE` often fails to work, so you will often have to write your own insert statement along the lines of

```
sqlQuery(odsHandle,paste0("insert into Utility.Daily.Data.Validation values (",*paste values here separated by a comma*,")")
```